# Is it possible to create a new gcloud SQL instance from code?

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-sql, gcloud

Is it possible to create a new gcloud SQL instance from code?

For an RnD project, I need to write a tool that is able to spin up and delete postgres database hosted with gcloud. I see this can be done for compute instances using [node](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@google-cloud/compute). I would preferbly like to be able to do it using node or python but am not tied down to any particilar lanauge.

Is this possible and do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Look for Ansible https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/scenario_guides/guide_gce.html

Answer (score 1):

Yes, The Cloud SQL [`instances.insert` API Call](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/admin-api/rest/v1beta4/instances/insert) can be used to create instances. However there is no nice nodejs package like `@google-cloud/compute`.  Instead you muse use the the generic, alpha [googleapis](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/googleapis/latest/sql/index.html) library.  This looks something like:

```
const {google} = require('googleapis');

const sql = google.sql({version: 'v1beta4'});

async function main () {
  const auth = new google.auth.GoogleAuth({scopes: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/sqlservice.admin']});
  const authClient = await auth.getClient();

  const project = "your-project-id-123";
  dbinstance = {
    // see https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/admin-api/rest/v1beta4/instances#DatabaseInstance
    // for parameters
  };

  const res = await sql.instances.insert({project: project, requestBody: dbinstance, auth: authClient});
  // ...
}
```